# How to keep track of information regarding fragments in Android

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments, android-spinner

I have a fragment which is sort of like a test. The user can choose from a spinners menu if this test has passed, failed or undecided. Once the user leaves this fragment and then comes back to it later, I want the spinners menu to display what the user had previously selected.

Can anyone tell me how to keep track of this information? I am a beginner with Java and Android programming. Also, let me know if further explanation is required.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on what scope you want to be able to refer to these tests in. For example, do you want these fragments to be emptied after the user closes the app, or not?

If it is just while in the app "session", you could just create an object in your fragment and override the `onResume` method to populate the spinners with the appropriate data.

If you want to save the info after the app is closed, there are a couple of options. For smaller sets of data you could use [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

if you have an undetermined amount of "tests", I would advise saving whatever data you need to a file, and parsing it to fill the fields in the fragments

Take a look at this to get an idea of how to save data: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: I was tempted to store the results in a temp text file and then read from it. I have 5 tests (so 5 fragments). I was hoping I could avoid storing the results in a text file.

Comment: Honestly storing it in 1 (or 5) file shouldn't be too difficult. Just delimiter the file in a way that is easy to parse. Maybe you could just put each answer on a new line?

Comment: Will try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to what your doing. I used shared preferences to save the string like so

Saving the string you got from the spinner in a fragment

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
SharedPreferences.Editor mSharedPreferencesEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();

mSharedPreferencesEditor.putString("my_unique_key", myString);

// commit changes
mSharedPreferencesEditor.apply();
```

Remember to always apply the changes after you made them and you can save as many strings as you want as long as they each have a unique key.

Then to retrieve the value just

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
String myStringValue = mSharedPreferences.getString("my_unique_key", null);
```

The second argument (null) will be returned if it could not find any data that had that unique key. (i.e if you haven't saved it yet)

You can also use another string instead of null like this

```
String myStringValue = mSharedPreferences.getString("my_unique_key", "could not find value");
```

or if you want to bundle a bunch of data together like say create an object to save a bunch of strings then save that object to a file I could show you that if you wanted to